# tesseract path MacOS

Tags: macos, tesseract

`import pytesseract from PIL import Image import os # Provide the path to the input image image_path = 'image1.png' # Load the image using PIL (Python Imaging Library) image = Image.open(image_path) # Set the path to the Tesseract executable tesseract_path = '/opt/local/bin/tesseract' # Check if the Tesseract executable exists if not os.path.exists(tesseract_path): raise FileNotFoundError('Tesseract executable not found at: {}'.format(tesseract_path)) # Set the path to the Tesseract executable in pytesseract pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = tesseract_path # Perform OCR using Tesseract recognized_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image) # Print the recognized text print(recognized_text)`
in this code,
`tesseract_path = '/opt/local/bin/tesseract'`
gives a FileNotFoundError

I installed tesseract by MacPorts. I have searched and tried lots of ways to get the path of the tesseract but all of them failed. What are some ways I can try to get the path?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an exhaustive search of your disk, starting at the top and looking for files called `tesseract` and discarding errors:

```
find / -name tesseract -type f 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: it still did not work so I uninstalled and reinstalled using homebrew and it is still not working...

Comment: If you have installed via **homebrew**, you will almost certainly need `/usr/local/bin/tesseract` or `/opt/local/bin/tesseract`